# Beta function inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality, special-functions, beta-function

I need to find values of the positive real parameters $a,b$ when $$B(a,b)<1,$$
where $B$ is beta function.

Is $a,b>1$ solution of the above inequality?

Answer (score 3):

$B(a,b)$ is a convex function with respect to both its parameters (see page 47 and beyond [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view)).
Both $\frac{\partial }{\partial a}B(a,b)$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial b}B(a,b)$ at $(a,b)=(1,1)$ are negative (equal to $\psi(1)-\psi(2)=-1$) and $B(1,1)=1$. Similarly, these partial derivatives are negative at any $(a,b)\in\{(x,y):x,y>1\}=E$, hence $B(a,b)<1$ holds over $E$ for sure.

$\hspace{1in}$[image]

$$\frac{d}{da}B(a,b) = B(a,b)\left[\psi(a)-\psi(a+b)\right] = B(a,b)\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{n+a+b}-\frac{1}{n+a}\right)<0. $$

Comment: Thanks a lot for a very nice answer!

Comment: Did you write that entire book?

Comment: @CyeWaldman: yes I did, they are my course notes.

Comment: Very nice indeed. I hope that it's okay that I downloaded a copy to peruse at my leisure.

Comment: @CyeWaldman: that is perfectly fine. Such notes are covered by a Creative Commons Share-Alike license.